# Precompiling Directives on a page AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am facing performance issue in my angular application.
Reason behind this is excessive use of a directive in a page.
Since I don't have enough time to break down that page into multiple pages.

I need a solution(server side .NET) in which we could pre-compile and pre-link directive to DOM elements inside the template and then serve that page to the client.

Or pre-compile and pre-link the directives asynchronously on the client side while doing other stuff.

```
<my-directive></my-directive> <!-- 1000 times within the single page -->
```

Thanks.

```
<label class="checkbox" ng-hide="ctrl.shouldHide()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{fieldId}}" ng-true-value="{{ctrl.valueId}}" ng-model="collection[vhFieldId]" />{{ ctrl.questionText }}
</label>
```

Comment: *"Or pre-compile and pre-link the directives asynchronously on the client side"* - this is more realistic. In general I doubt you need to have all 1000 directives available at the same time (does you users have 1000 hands and 2000 eyes?). Most likely you can even lazy-compile them.

Comment: yes, you are right and we tried loading parts of controls asynchronously by adding them in chunks but this approach leads to sluggish UI which is irritating for user. so we decided to load all at once then allow user to interact with UI.

Comment: I see. You could then indeed load al at once but compile on demand.

Comment: You could probably improve the directive too, and if it's 1000 elements I guess you use `ngRepeat` do you use `track by` with it?

Comment: Post directive code, it could be improved probably.

Comment: @maurycy        yeah but my current page structure doesn't allow to opt for ngRepeat option. :(

Comment: Post directive code like @dfsq asked, we will try to optimize it :)

Comment: I assume you use angular 1.3.x or higher, then start with one-way binding for things that will not change:
`<input type="checkbox" id="{{::fieldId}}" ng-true-value="{{::ctrl.valueId}}" ng-model="collection[vhFieldId]" />{{ ::ctrl.questionText }}`

Comment: No using 1.2, recently tried upgrading to 1.3 for this reason only but had some issues in the application functionalities so we had to revert the changes for the time being.

Comment: Then you really should add 3rd party directive: `bind-once` number of watchers has a big impact on pages + number of DOM operations. If you define your directive to replace the tag with template it might be troublesome

Comment: Ok, I will try this one. But the original question remain still unanswered. Can we async-compile and async-link a particular template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95909/discussion-between-ashutosh-singh-and-maurycy).

Answer (score -1):

You can not "pre-compile and pre-link directive to DOM elements" on the server side as there is no DOM on the server side and angular is a client side technology anyway.

What might be possible to do is to better write the Directive so that for example it will only have to compile (parse) the template once and only link each instance. This is assuming that the performance issues you have are indeed related to the said directive.

Peformance issue can again be cause by many many things and sometime something trivial such as setting a minimum height to a directive could be very helpful (because if would prevent page-reflows).

To get any actual help here you would really need to share some code.